# Separate vs. joined words (hyphen or not)

Tags: american-english, british-english, hyphenation

English is not my native language, and sometimes it's confusing.. Especially uk-english vs. american and hyphens

Can someone explain a bit when to use which of these?

It's for a global english website

```
football team, footballteam, football-team
movie fan, moviefan, movie-fan

"football-players/fans" vs. "football players/fans"
```

Thanks

Comment: I am British, and would write all three examples you give as two separate words with no hyphen.

Comment: @WS2: as would Americans (even though we usually mean something quite different by *"football"*).